# How to speed up SPP throughput in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to get a Xamarin app to receive around 10 kbps of SPP data through bluetooth from our custom PCB. The BC127 module on the PCB can send a maximum packet size of 255 bytes, so the app needs to receive a packet every ~25ms. I'm using the packets to separate the data, so they need to be received one at a time.

The test app is constantly trying to receive data, however sometimes when it arrives back at the start of the receive method, there are 2+ packets waiting in the receive stream. My question is, what is causing the huge delays in my bluetooth receive method? I've attached the method below. After connecting to the bluetooth module, the app does nothing but run this method in a while(true) loop.

```
public byte[] ReadBluetoothPacket()
    {
        int bytesAvailable = 0;
        while (bytesAvailable == 0)                                     // Wait for packet to arrive
        {
            bytesAvailable = stream.BaseInputStream.Available();        // Find out how big the packet is
        }
        byte[] result = new byte[bytesAvailable];
        _socket.InputStream.Read(result, 0, bytesAvailable);            // Add the bytes to the buffer
        return result; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue was due to the Android OS doing background tasks which were holding up my receive thread. As it turned out to only be an intermittent problem, rewriting the data receiver to handle multiple packets at once solved it.